# issue with Entity Framework Core 3.1 with FK errors especially with lots of rows

Tags: exception, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

Sometimes we get FK constraint errors.

I wonder whether it's due to a problem with the version of EF Core it is using - 3.1.2.

I want evidence to state that we need to upgrade it - as the powers that be are incredibly reluctant to make changes (they see it as risk).

We've checked out the config.

What known issue could this be with that version of EF Core?

Perhaps it sometimes cannot guarantee which entity is inserted first hence the ID is unknown sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

FK violations are typically caused when EF is told to attach/associate an entity that isn't actually representing rows in the underlying database, or the relationship between entities isn't set up correctly. A common bug around this is when a relationship between two entities accidentally gets wired up to the wrong value rather than the FK property you expect. One-to-One relationships are a good example where by default a `.HasOne(x => x.Second).WithOne(x => x.First)` will join on the two table PKs rather than an expected First.SecondId or Second.FirstId you might expect. Such relationships need to be explicitly configured.

Comment: hi @StevePy the system processes hundreds of rows at a time so I'm not convinced its a case of an incorrectly configured relationship in our EF code (but I'm continuing to investigate that).
However, I'm beginning to wonder if there is some glitch when processing en-masse (It happily processes large varieties of records most of the time)?

Comment: When inserting entities that are set up with navigation properties that are populated it will use those to ensure records are inserted in the correct order. Tracking down the issue will be difficult without seeing the code managing the insert. Factors to consider would be how long a DbContext instance is open while processing, how records are being created or any scenarios where a reference might get reused rather than re-created or duplicate instances for the same record. The exact exception message or messages would also be needed.